# EOF equivalent method in python?

Tags: python

Is there any equivalent method in python which will be a replacement for **EOF** in C

Let suppose, a file contains 3 lines. I wanna iterate the file until the End of File.

```
>>> fp.seek(0)
>>> with open(file,'rb') as openfileobject:
               for chunk in iter(partial(openfileobject.read,1024),''):
                           openfileobject.read()
```

The above code is in infinite loop. I know the below code will do the trick for me.

```
>>> for line in fp:
          print(line)
```

But, i am willing to manually iterate the file pointer. That's why i am searching for eof equivalent in python.

Comment: do you try to take last row of your file?

Comment: Not the last row. Every row until EOF

Comment: EOF means End Of File. "Every row until EOF" doesn't make any sense. Do you mean `\n`?

Comment: Suppose my file contains: a \n b\n c\n ... then i wanna iterate until end of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. The most immediate bug is that your sentinel value needs to be a `bytes` object, not a `str`, since you open the file in binary mode. That is why it's looping forever. So use `b''`:

```
with open(file,'rb') as openfileobject:
    for chunk in iter(partial(openfileobject.read,1024), b''):
        openfileobject.read()
```

You need to use `b''` because the way the two-argument `iter` works is that the value needs to be a value returned by the function you pass in.
The function `fileobject.read` will return `b''` when the file object is exhausted, and Python deals with `EOF` itself. So for all intents and purposes, you only should care about `b''`. If `fileobject` was `open`ed in test mode, `fileobject.read` will return a `''` string object instead of `bytes` object.

But actually, you will only do a single iteration this way, because on the first iteration you call `openfileobject.read`, which reads until the EOF. The `chunk` is actually the <=1024 byte chunk you need!

So what you actually want is:

```
with open(file,'rb') as openfileobject:
    for chunk in iter(partial(openfileobject.read,1024), b''):
        do_something(chunck)
```

**Edit in response to comments:**

So, I think what you want for `do_something` is something like this:

```
with open(file,'rb') as openfileobject:
    for chunk in iter(partial(openfileobject.read,1024), b''):
        for line in chunk.splitlines() # this strips the new-lines
            print(line) # for example, print...
```

But keep in mind, when you read your file in "chunks" your lines will be fragmented (unless the lines are aligned to by the chunksize to begin with...)

Comment: Well, then how can I print every line from my file through chunck??

Comment: @W.Jack I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @W.Jack Ok, I've edited with what I believe you are looking for

Comment: Yes.. thanks... And... so, there is no direct equivalent of EOF like C in python?

Comment: @W.Jack the empty string *is* the equivalent. A python file object will return an empty string the next time you `read` from a file, after having encountered the EOF.